# Objective C Class Methods vs C Functions

Tags: objective-c, c, function, class-method

While working on on open source project, I came across the following C function declaration and implementation:

```
// FSNData.h
NSString *stringForMimeType(MimeType type);

@interface FSNData : NSObject
// All the expected objective-c property and instance method declarations
@end

// FSNData.m
#import "FSNData.h"

// where 'type' is an enum
// this does work as expected
NSString *stringForMimeType(MimeType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case MimeType_image_jpeg: return @"image/jpeg";
        case MimeType_image_png:  return @"image/png";
        default:
            NSLog(@"ERROR: FSNData: unknown MimeType: %d", type);

        // do not return "application/octet-stream"; instead, let the recipient guess
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type
        return nil;
    }
}

@implementation

// all properties and methods defined in FSData.h implemented as expected

@end
```

This example could easily be re-written as a class level method with out any problem. As it is, using `stringFormMimeType()` sill requires importing the `FSNData` header file anyway.

Looking at [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH43-SW1), it states only:

> Because Objective-C rests on a foundation of ANSI C, you can freely
>   intermix straight C code with Objective-C code. Moreover, your code
>   can call functions defined in non-Cocoa programmatic interfaces, such
>   as the BSD library interfaces in /usr/include.

There is no mention of when C functions should favour Objective-C methods.

The only benefit I can see at this point, is that calling the above function, as opposed to a class method, some Objective-C runtime call(s) would be skipped. In a typical use case of `FSNData`, this would not give a noticeable boost in performance to the user (probably even to developers)*.

What benefit exists (other than coding style) for favouring a C function over a class method?

*`FSNData` is used as part of the [FSNetworking](https://github.com/foursquare/FSNetworking) library, so I doubt there would be thousands upon thousands of network operations being performed during any application's life cycle.

Comment: Style, program structuring (clearly associating the method with the class), and a slight bit of (very weak) access control are all I can think of.  (But I see that @ipmcc mentions inheritance, and there are a few things there as well.)

Comment: I prefer class method because Objective-C methods offer named parameter, which C functions do not

Comment: @onmyway133 I was specifically trying to stay away from personal preferences  (i.e. **other than coding style**) and looking for a technical reason.

Comment: @MikeD it's not personal preferences, it 's because of `name parameter`, which makes it clearer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, C (or C++) implementations are very useful:

- For Abstraction
- For Reusability
- When making medium and large scale programs
- In performance critical paths
- For 'Interior' implementations

> What benefit exists (other than coding style) for favouring a C function over a class method?

- ObjC messaging introduces indirect function calls. These are firewalls for optimizers.
- C functions can easily restrict access, whereas 'private' ObjC implementations may be looked up using the ObjC runtime, or accidentally overridden.
- C functions may be removed from your executable if not referenced, or they may be made private. If you write reusable code (and you should), this can have a huge impact on your binary sizes and load times -- C functions which are not referenced/used may be removed, but ObjC types and methods will be preserved (including everything they reference). This is why your app's binary size may grow significantly when you use only small part of an ObjC static library -- every objc class in the library is preserved. If that library were C or C++, then you could get by with very small growth because you need only what is referenced. What is or is not referenced is easier to prove with C and C++.
- C functions can be inlined, either during compilation or during Link Time Optimization phases.
- The compiler and optimizers are able to do much optimization with C functions (e.g. inter-procedural optimizations), but very little with ObjC methods because they are always indirect.
- To avoid ObjC message dispatch overhead (as you mentioned)
- Potential for additional reference counting operations and autorelease pool activity when interacting with ObjC objects.

Of course you won't always hurt paying for things you don't need or use -- and remember that ObjC class methods have some benefits over C functions, too. So, just look at C or C++ implementations as another tool in your toolbox. I find them very useful as complexity and project sizes increase, and they can be used to make your programs much faster. Just do what you are least likely to regret in 2015 ;)

Comment: I think the answer by @ipmcc has valuable info as well. Could you have a link for how and when functions get stripped?

Comment: @MikeD `man strip` would be an intro. this, used in conjunction with optimization and proper dead code elimination (or unreachable code) at various stages (e.g. compilation, linking) allow the tools to identify what is and what is not referenced, or not reachable by the program. this is useful for C and C++, but does not apply to ObjC symbols (and what they reference) because you have the ability to easily reference them dynamically via the runtime (e.g. `NSClassFromString`, `NSSelectorFromString`), so all are preserved by default because Xcode adds the necessary flags on your behalf. (cont)

Comment: @MikeD a C function is 'referenced' if it's called externally (it may be removed if inlined in every case), or if you reference it by address (e.g. pass it around as a function pointer). if the toolchain realizes that you call it only from unreachable code, then it may also be eliminated. i'm actually going to reword that bit.

Comment: Thank you. That helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 10):

You already touched on the marginal performance difference of avoiding an `objc_msgSend` call. Objective-C class methods are also subject to overriding in subclasses, so implementing a method in C will prevent it from being overridden in a subclass. Relatedly, because of that runtime inheritance/polymorphism, an Objective-C method can never be inlined, whereas a C function can potentially be inlined by the compiler for added performance.

When it comes to avoiding `objc_msgSend`, a wise man once told me, "If the overhead of `objc_msgSend` is too great for you, Objective-C is probably the wrong tool for the job."